Cannot read property 'clip' of undefined while creating web app in Google Earth Engine
I was trying to create an app using GEE to visualize the images from the year 2000 to 2020 at an interval of 5 years for selected municipalities. After running the code, the dropdown box is displayed, and when I choose a municipality it shows:

Line 212: Cannot read property 'clip' of undefined.

This is the line: var layer= images[year].clip(localBody). How can I remove this error?
// Defining our own styles for the underlying base map


// Set the base map style to 'Hybrid'
Map.setOptions('hybrid');

var mapStyle = [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
];
Map.setOptions('mapStyle', {mapStyle: mapStyle});

//Visual Parameters
var ALparams= {
  min:1,
  max:2,
  palette: ['red']
  };

//Importing abandoned land 
var images= {
'2000': ee.Image('projects/ee-bibekpoudel245/assets/Abandoned2000'),
'2005': ee.Image('projects/ee-bibekpoudel245/assets/Abandoned2005'),
'2010': ee.Image('projects/ee-bibekpoudel245/assets/Abandoned2010'),
'2015':ee.Image('projects/ee-bibekpoudel245/assets/Abandoned2015'),
'2020': ee.Image('projects/ee-bibekpoudel245/assets/Abandoned2020')};

//Importing Shapefile of Gandaki Province with local bodies
//Importing Shapefile of Gandaki Province with local bodies
var province = province2;
//Getting the list of local bodies names
var localBodyNames= province.aggregate_array('GaPa_NaPa');

//Creating a label for the year dropdown
var yearLabel= ui.Label('Select a year of abandonment');

//Creating a dropdown for the years of abandonment
var yearDropdown= ui.Select({
  items: ['2000','2005','2010','2015','2020'],
});
//Creating a label for the dropdown
var label= ui.Label('Select a local body:');

//Creating a dropdown for the local bodies
var dropdown= ui.Select({
  items: localBodyNames.getInfo(),
  onChange: function(localBodyName){
    //Getting the selected local body
    var localBody= province.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GaPa_NaPa', localBodyName)).first();
  
  //Getting the selected Year
  var year= yearDropdown.getValue();
  
  //Updating the map with the selected local body and the abandoned layer for the selected year
    var layer= images[year].clip(localBody);
    Map.layers().reset([ui.Map.Layer(layer)]);
  }
});



//Creating a panel with the labels, the dropdowns
var panel= ui.Panel([label,dropdown, yearLabel, yearDropdown]);

//Adding the panel to the map
Map.add(panel);

//Centering the map on the local bodies
Map.centerObject(province);


As soon as you select a municipality from the dropdown, the onChange function is called. That function attempts to grab and clip an image based on the selected year in yearDropdown. If yearDropdown isn't set yet, you'll get undefined instead of an image, which explains the error message.
Here's one way to solve this: 1) set default value properties for both dropdowns so they're never undefined and 2) use a button to trigger adding things to the map, rather than adding them automatically when the dropdowns change.
The button would be a modified version of your original onChange function:
var submitButton = ui.Button({label: "Add to map", onClick: function() {
  var localBodyName = dropdown.getValue();
  var year= yearDropdown.getValue();

  var localBody= province.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GaPa_NaPa', localBodyName)).first();
  var layer= images[year].clip(localBody);
  Map.layers().reset([ui.Map.Layer(layer)]);
}});

And the dropdowns should specify a default value in case a user clicks submit before choosing an option:
var localBodyNames= province.aggregate_array('GaPa_NaPa').getInfo();
var dropdown= ui.Select({
  items: localBodyNames,
  // Default to the first local body
  value: localBodyNames[0],
});

var yearDropdown= ui.Select({
  items: ['2000','2005','2010','2015','2020'],
  value: '2000',
});

Your script assets aren't public, so I made a demo using dummy data that you should be able to adapt: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8df75a69ec363a75a5164b4c54e99d43

If I do this way I can't select the images for other years except 2000. Is there another way that We can select any of these years?

Good point - you would have to change the year and then re-select a local body to update the map, which isn't great. I modified my answer with a solution that's more involved, but should work better.

Thank you very much. The code worked as I wanted.
